# Create nested serializer of same type with depth option support

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Assume there is a child and parent relation in models, such as:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
  parent = models.ForeignKey('Foo', related_name='children')
```

Now I want to have a serializer to show children of a `Foo` object, something like this:

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  children = FooSerializer(many=True)
  class Meta:
    model = Foo
    fields = '__all__'
```

But this gives me error that it does not recognize `FooSerializer` when creating that class which is correct regarding the way python parses the class. How could I implement such relation and have a serializer to get its children.
I must mention that I want to able to use `depth` option of nested serializer.

I am using django 2.2.7 and rest framework 3.10.1.

**Edit**

There may be some numbers of nested levels which it must be stopped using `depth` option, after some levels it must be flatten, so I wanted to able to use `depth` option along nested serializer.

Comment: Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39104575/django-rest-framework-recursive-nested-parent-serialization/39122426

Comment: Also not sure if it works or not but try `depth=1` parameter. See details here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization

Comment: As you guessed it does not work with depth parameter

Comment: Why `depth` over `nested serializer` ?

Comment: My question is incomplete somehow, there may be some numbers of nested relation and I want to be able to stop in some level so using depth is crucial in my case.

Comment: If I understand the mechanism of depth, I could implement this in `__init__` or serializer method field, but currently I have no clue how `depth` controls the level of serialization.

Answer (score 2):

[**`depth`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization) attribute is for ForeignKey relationships, In your case, it's reverse-FK relation, So it won't work

---

You can achieve the ***`depth`*** like feature by using ***multiple serializer*** in **Nested configuration**.

### Example 1: result similar to `depth=1`

```
class FooBaseSerializerLevel1(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = '__all__'


class FooBaseSerializerLevel0(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    children = FooBaseSerializerLevel1(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = '__all__'
```

### Example 2: result similar to `depth=2`

```
class FooBaseSerializerLevel2(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = '__all__'


class FooBaseSerializerLevel1(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    children = FooBaseSerializerLevel2(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = '__all__'


class FooBaseSerializerLevel0(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    children = FooBaseSerializerLevel1(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = '__all__'
```

---

The key point is that, **do not define the `children` where you want to stop the nested effect**

Comment: I tried it but it does not work with `depth` option

Comment: doesn't work with depth? I don't ask to include `depth` I don't understand what you are trying to say

Comment: @MohsenTamiz This solution will work as-is, I have tested and verified

Comment: I mentioned in my question that I want to be able to set depth option of serializer, for example setting it to 1 means just one level of children would be shown. As @neverwalkaloner has said in the question comment this solution is just valid when there is not `depth` option.

Comment: `depth` is for **`ForeignKey`** relationships, In your case, it's ***reverse-FK relation***

Comment: I have edited the question to cover my inconvenience in asking the question, thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Based on another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59161539/2335245), I wrote a version which supports depth option:

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  children = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

  def get_children(self, obj):
    if obj.children:
        depth = getattr(self.Meta, 'depth', None)
        if not depth:
            depth = self.context.get('depth', 0)

        if depth:
            return SessionSerializer(obj.children.all(),
                                     many=True,
                                     context={'depth': depth - 1}).data
        else:
            return [child.id for child in obj.children.all()]
    else:
        return []
```

It supports depth option too.