# Use serializer in itself Django

Tags: django

How can I use my serializer for an instance in the serializer. So in itself
Ex:

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    parent = CompanySerializer
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ("id", "name", "parent")
```

Django doesn't recognize it and asks to create a CompanySerializer..

Comment: there is a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39122426/843999

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Rest Framework Recursive Nested Parent Serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39104575/django-rest-framework-recursive-nested-parent-serialization)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate serializer and call it `ParentCompanySerializer`. Even that can work. So something like,

```
class ParentCompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
       model = Company
       fields = ("id", "name")

class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ("id", "name", "parent")
    parent = ParentCompanySerializer()
```

Comment: A parent can also have a higher parent. So that will cause problems with this implementation I think?

Comment: If you see, I have omitted `parent` from ParentCompanySerializer on purpose, because I made an assumption that you require only direct parent and not parent of parent and so on. Now with my suggestion, parent's parent is not considered for serialisation and hence won't be an issue.

Comment: I don't get that lost one?

Comment: You can pick and choose fields to serialise right so in ParentCompanySerializer class I have only kept two fields id and name. With no parent field defined in serializer, there won't be serialization done for it. I believe if I am looking for one company's data that can suffice, unless you want complete hierarchy.